# Interactive spline chart for C# WPF/Winforms

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, data-visualization

I'm looking to buy or build a spline chart (just like one [here](http://visifire.com/silverlight_spline_charts_gallery.php)) in C# .NET for which the data points can be draged by mouse and the resulting underlying dataset changes.

Could some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been making interactive spline charting using native .NET WinForm charting controls. MSDN has an expansive demo of these features, one of which is chart interactivity.

[Samples Environment for Microsoft Chart Controls](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the Silverlight toolkit.... [LINK](http://silverlight.codeplex.com) 
But what is the problem you are having with the Visifire chatrs you have shown in example ?